# How to access /sdcard/Android/media folder using scoped storage on Android 11+?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-11, scoped-storage

Wanted to access the images inside /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/<other_app_package>/ folder programmatically on Android 11+.

For example, WhatsApp's status files (images/videos) are saved in: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"

What we are trying to figure out is, using scoped storage, how to access the files inside .Statuses on Android 11+?
If we use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, then we are able to access but this is not recommended by Google Play.

Following apps are able to access the files from the new path with just READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on Android 11+
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=recover.deleted.messages.messagesrestore
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.downlood.sav.whmedia

Since there are many apps that access images inside Android/media folder already on Android 11+ without all file access, does anyone know how to achieve the same?

Comment: Please read a few stackoverflow pages tagged `android`. You are number ### who wants this.

Comment: Have gone through those questions and the solution are either "it's not possible" or the one that works on Android SDK 29. So have posted a question requesting solution for Android 10+ with the app links that actually achieves this.

Comment: Isn't Android Q/10 == sdk 29?

Comment: Have updated the question, @blackapps. Thanks for pointing out. Google Play has stopped accepting updates with target SDK 29. So a solution with target SDK 29 won't be useful anyway.

Comment: You can let the user pick the wanted directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: duplicate questions

Comment: @blackapps, the apps I listed above seems to be reading from /sdcard/Android/Media without asking users to select a directory. They have recent updates to their apps on Google Play as well. So how they have achieved it on Android 11+?

Comment: Probably they do not target 11 but lower.

Comment: Yeah, @blackapps. I guess you are right. The SDK 30+ requirement for app updates is from November 2021 (https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk). The app updates for apps that are working with Android/Media are in Aug to Oct. Will delete the post.